# How to match fragment of a cell with another cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have such formula, which matches the content of whole cells:

[image]

How can I match fragments of values in C column, like this (so A2 would be TRUE):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Replace `match` with either `search` (case-insensitive) or `find` (case-sensitive), taking the concatenation of the strings in column C as the text to search in. To avoid false matches for things like "DogHorse" resulting from concatenation, I use `join` to join the entries in C,  separating them by newlines `char(10)`.

```
=arrayformula(not(iserror(search(B2:B, join(char(10), C2:C)))))
```

if case doesn't matter, or

```
=arrayformula(not(iserror(find(B2:B, join(char(10), C2:C)))))
```

if it does.

Comment: Unforutently I didn't got it work as expected. See: https://i.imgur.com/pwegWdG.png or https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QW3PAq-mB0Sr5kbhiAJZcf31VIFCrmWTj9TuO6Dklw0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You are searching for A in B. Did you mean to search for B in A?

Comment: Does it matter? It doesn't work as well, only the result is opposite.

Comment: It does matter, because "is a substring of" is not a symmetric relation. I'm out of here.